# Azure Logicapps for VM poweroff/poweron notifications

Tags: azure, automation, virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

**Is it possible to create a logicapp that monitors a specific vm and sends an e-mail notification on poweroff/poweron or CPU usage % for example?**
I've read into Event Grid, but it seems to cater more towards resource creation/deletion notifications rather than specific vm signals.
I also understand it would be possible to just add an alert on the vm, however these alerts don't seem to be customizable and we need to be able to customize the e-mail to send, something I know is possible to do with logicapps.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you can do it just by alert. But when you create action group in alert rule, do not chooose send email under "**Notification**" tab as below screenshot.
[image]

Instead, choose "Logic App" under "**Actions**" tab as below screenshot shown and choose a logic app which you already created(with "**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger).
[image]

The logic app with "**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger should be like:
[image]
Then you can customize the email in logic app "**Send an email(V2)**" action

Comment: If the solution is helpful to your requirement, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: done, thank you once again it was exactly what I was looking for!